# I'm getting this error "manifest authoring error c1010001: Values of attribute "name" not equal in different manifest snippets."

Tags: c#, c++

I'm facing this problem in VS2012 while adding manifest to a C++ exe project.

To Add manifest : 
Project Properties->Manifest Tool->Input/Output->Additional Manifest File
Added Manifest File Path here.

My Manifest File is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity name="CompressionUtilities" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86"></assemblyIdentity>
  <clrClass clsid="{DEE4E35C-E3E4-4E9A-9B88-433DB0D89BE8}" progid="CILCompressionUtilitiesLib.CompressClass" threadingModel="Both" name="CILCompressionUtilitiesLib.CompressClass" runtimeVersion=""></clrClass>
  <clrSurrogate clsid="{A75D2CF3-CCD5-45B5-A3EA-E346EB1A28B0}" name="CILCompressionUtilitiesLib.CompressionAlgorithmEnum"></clrSurrogate>
  <clrSurrogate clsid="{5A055905-06F8-46AD-B5FE-A52668CE1DB6}" name="CILCompressionUtilitiesLib.ExtractResultEnum"></clrSurrogate>
  <clrSurrogate clsid="{E9E5240A-ED2C-45FB-AD23-66F74209275E}" name="CILCompressionUtilitiesLib.EncryptionTypeEnum"></clrSurrogate>
  <file name="CompressionUtilities.dll" hashalg="SHA1"></file>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 3):

This option is for crafting a manifest file by merging manifest fragments. This leads to the conflict you had. (All your fragments have a different name that can't be merged into one file)

To create dependencies you can use  Project Properties->Linker->Manifest File->Aditional Manifest Dependencies.
Here is the syntax for it: [/ManifestDependency on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0y5khy.aspx)